# Textarea at 100% width fills container but div at 100% width expands the parent

Tags: html, css, textarea, width

I'm having an interesting problem that I'm hoping someone can help with. I have a textarea that when set at 100% width, fills the parent div that it's in. HOWEVER, if I replace that with a div, the div blows out the parent divs width to now fit the child's content instead of wrapping.

I've tried various approaches (display:inline-block, display:table, display:table-cell, box-sizing...) I've used span, div, p and table/tr/td.. all result in the following overflow.

[image: TextArea]

[image: Div Tag]

[image: Box-sizing src]

I've inspected the source, and all I see is the textarea's width being set to 100% with no other styles affecting it.

Is there's an attribute I'm missing when I'm inspecting?

Comment: Including images of code is basically worthless. Please link to a live example, create a jsfiddle or use the snippet tool available here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you simply need to utilize [border box](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp):

```
*{ box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this had no affect on the text.

Comment: @Steve can you put together a live example then?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your `div` might have `padding` also. Now when you add the padding with `width: 100%`, the child will basically overflow the parent cause of the extra padding.

To include padding within the width try providing your `div` a `box-sizing: border-box;`.

You can read more about [box-sizing here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: Did you see the images? I'm not sure how padding could affect this. I added box-sizing to the div tag and there were no changes.

Comment: We don't see images. We see code here. Looking at the images it indeed seemed like a `box-sizing` issue. If you want more help, please add your code or a demo fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the complexity of the application, I'll need to strip it down to the basics and figure it out. I was hoping that there was a structural component of the textarea that I didn't know about.

Thanks,